# if quit app and then reopen the app then it will asking again login in swift?

Tags: swift, authentication, gmail

My app is integrated with google authentication, it is working both gmail login and logout functionality. but my problem is, if quit app and then reopen the app then it will asking again gmail login. i tried to search the examples for the above requirement, but no relavant examples found. can you help for this requirement.

Comment: You have to check if he is logged in and them past to the next viewController. Can you post your code trying to do this?

Comment: my code too long, can you give your mail id?

Comment: With this code you can check if its logged in them you fo to the nextViewController and don't show the loggin screen GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()

Comment: thank you, i check 'GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()'

Comment: i tried this code, it not worked.                                                               var signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.delegate = self
    if  signIn.hasAuthInKeychain(){
        signIn.signInSilently()
    }else{
        signIn.signIn()
    }